# Computing K-means clustering on Location data in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have a dataset of users and their music plays, with every play having location data. For every user i want to cluster their plays to see if they play music in given locations.

I plan on using the sci-kit learn k-means package, but how do I get this to work with location data, as opposed to its default, euclidean distance?

An example of it working would really help me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use k-means with anything other than Euclidean distance.

K-means is *not* designed to work with other distance metrics (see k-medians for Manhattan distance, k-medoids aka. PAM for arbitrary other distance functions).

The concept of k-means is **variance minimization**. And variance is essentially the same as squared Euclidean distances, but it is *not* the same as other distances.

Have you considered DBSCAN? sklearn should have DBSCAN, and it should by now have index support to make it fast.

Comment: Yes, its a project so i was going to start by using k-means, and then use the more accurate DBSCAN. Maybe i'll just skip k-means. Thanks!

Comment: DBSCAN vs. k-means isn't a matter of accuracy. They cluster by different principles, so the results aren't "more fine", but usually just something very different. k-means minimizes variances. DBSCAN discovers density connected components.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Poor choice of words on my behalf. It just suits my cluster density and shape better.

Answer (score 2):

Is the data already in vector space e.g. gps coordinates? If so you can cluster on it directly, lat and lon are close enough to x and y that it shouldn't matter much. If not, preprocessing will have to be applied to convert it to a vector space format (table lookup of locations to coords for instance). Euclidean distance is a good choice to work with vector space data.

To answer the question of whether they played music in a given location, you first fit your kmeans model on their location data, then find the "locations" of their clusters using the cluster_centers_ attribute. Then you check whether any of those cluster centers are close enough to the locations you are checking for. This can be done using thresholding on the distance functions in scipy.spatial.distance.

It's a little difficult to provide a full example since I don't have the dataset, but I can provide an example given arbitrary x and y coords instead if that's what you want.

Also note KMeans is probably not ideal as you have to manually set the number of clusters "k" which could vary between people, or have some more wrapper code around KMeans to determine the "k". There are other clustering models which can determine the number of clusters automatically, such as meanshift, which may be more ideal in this case and also can tell you cluster centers.